# trouble understanding how reversing a linked list works

Tags: javascript, linked-list, reverse

I'm reversing a linked list. I know it's a trivial task, but I have an understanding issue.
I'm using a class syntax in JavaScript

```
class LinkedList {
    constructor(value) {
        this.head = {
            value: value,
            next: null
        };
        this.tail = this.head;
        this.length = 1;
    }
    append(value) {
      const newNode = {
        value: value,
        next: null
      }
      this.tail.next = newNode;
      this.tail = newNode;
      this.length++;
      return this;
    }
    reverse() {
      if (!this.head.next) {
        return this.head;
      }
      let first = this.head;
      this.tail = this.head;
      let second = first.next;
      let temp = null

      while(second) {
        temp = second.next;
        second.next = first;
        first = second;
        second = temp;

        console.log('first', first)
      }

      this.head.next = null;
      console.log('first after', first)
      this.head = first;
      return this
    }
}
let myLinkedList = new LinkedList(5);
myLinkedList.append(1)
myLinkedList.append(99)
myLinkedList.reverse()
```

The thing I can't understand is this: after the last iteration of the while loop the `first` variable should point to this object (it's `console.log('first', first)`):

```
{ value: 99,
  next: { value: 1, next: { value: 5, next: [Circular] } } }
```

However, after the loop is over, `first` starts pointing at
this one, which gives us the right answer (it's  `console.log('first after', first))`:

```
{ value: 99,
  next: { value: 1, next: { value: 5, next: null } } }
```

I even tried to draw diagrams but still fail to understand why it happens **(why `first.next.next.next` starts pointing at null)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the line `this.head.next = null;`.
`first.next.next.next` and `this.head` point to the same node: `5`.

Below is your code with some extra comments:

```
    reverse() {
      // At the start of the invocation, the linked list will be:
      // head: 5
      // (mid): 1
      // tail: 99

      if (!this.head.next) {
        return this.head;
      }
      let first = this.head;
      this.tail = this.head;
      let second = first.next;
      let temp = null

      while(second) {
        temp = second.next;
        second.next = first;
        first = second;
        second = temp;

        console.log('first', first)
      }

      // At this point, the `next` pointer of each node is updated together
      // with `this.tail`, but `this.head` still refers to the previous head (now tail).
      // `this.head` and `first.next.next.next` reference the same node '5'.

      this.head.next = null;
      console.log('first after', first)

      // Only after this assignment will the head be updated, resulting in the following linked list:
      // head: 99
      // (mid): 1
      // tail: 5
      this.head = first;

      return this
    }
```